# Umbraco Indexing Error Filling Up Logs

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, lucene.net

I am continually getting an Umbraco indexing error in our logs which seem to correspond with very high cpu usage on the site. Here is the error:

> ERROR UmbracoExamine.DataServices.UmbracoLogService - [Thread 99]
>   Provider=InternalIndexer, NodeId=-1 System.Exception: Error indexing
>   queue items,read past EOF, IndexSet: InternalIndexSet

Is this because the node that it is trying to index has an id of -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with node ID being -1, Root node of Umbraco is always -1.

> The reason for your error is you have segment( for e.g. **segment_c** file) files with 0k capacity in your index folder ~/App_Data/TEMP/ExamineIndexes/Internal.

You should delete those files with empty segment and everything will work fine.

For the permanent solution you have to find the root cause why these empty files are left behind. For e.g. Content modification when backup is running would not allow index optimiser to delete file as backup is going on.

For detailed discussion on this, see [Link](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/45649-[UmbracoExamine]-(InternalIndexer)Error-indexing-queue-items,read-past-EOF)